# while register user in laravel it also auto register in chamilo in background

Tags: laravel, api, background-process, registration, chamilo-lms

how to achieve registering user from laravel so it will automatically get register in chamilo(lms) in background is there any API or library we can use for post from laravel and get in chamilo?

Answer (score 0):

there is libarary for chamilo in register.soap.php path(projectfolder\main\webservices\registration.soap.php)file used CreateUser() and pass require parametr using soap api. user get auto created from another domain